# Have all data structures an abstract data type?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, heap, abstract-data-type

I some places I'm reading contradictory things about this topic, for example here

[Is heap an abstract data type? If so, what about priority queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154627/is-heap-an-abstract-data-type-if-so-what-about-priority-queues)

The answer was:

> both priority queues & heaps **are** data types (more accurate; **abstract data type or ADT**)

But here

[Is Heap considered an Abstract Data Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124644/is-heap-considered-an-abstract-data-type)

> **Heap is not an ADT. It is a Data Structure.**

And for example in the book:

*Java Software Structures,International Edition [John Lewis, Joseph Chase]*

it has a heap as ADT and a DS with this code:

```
public interface HeapADT<T> extends BinaryTreeADT<T>
{
/**
* Adds the specified object to this heap.
*
* @param obj the element to be added to this heap
*/
public void addElement (T obj);
/**
* Removes element with the lowest value from this heap.
*
* @return the element with the lowest value from this heap
*/
public T removeMin();
/**
* Returns a reference to the element with the lowest value in
* this heap.
*
* @return a reference to the element with the lowest value in this heap
*/
public T findMin();
}
```

The main question is if we say that all behaviour definition of a DS is an ADT, for example

- **List** is an ADT of Static and Dynamic Array, linked-list
- **Stack**, is an ADT, but you can implement the stack with an array or a linked list, but finally this stack is a data structure
- **Queue**, the same that Stack
- **Heap**, the same that Stack

So abstract data type is the behaviour that you'll implement with another data structure that has its own ADT.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: This question has been asked to death here and on softwareengineering, as well. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148747/abstract-data-type-and-data-structure, or just do a Google search on [difference between abstract data type and data structure].

Comment: Might softwareengineering is a best place, but i think that a google search is not enought because have a lot of "versions", and what is the reall source of true about this, if some people defined heap like ADT, and antoher like and DS. And some people define the heap like and a DT, when you can implement this with pointer too. But I think that some people only say this like parrots because never put references of a book or similinar, and like I did, some times this books have contradictions betwen them like Algorithms 4th and Java Software Structures.

Comment: Like you can see in the second question from here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148747/abstract-data-type-and-data-structure

```ADT: List
DS:  ArrayList, LinkedList...```

But if you read this DATA STRUCTURES IN C++ by N. S. KUTTI, P. Y. PADHYE they define the Array like ADT and DT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Abstract Data Type, as you said, describes the behavior (or "semantics") of an entity (usually from the point of view of those who use that entity). So in your examples, stacks, queues, lists, etc...

A data structure is just a particular way of organizing data. So it is just *one* way to represent a data type.

> The main question is if we say that all behaviour definition of a DS is an ADT

I wouldn't say that. If I define a data structure that represent the classical example of a `Car` (again, considering a data structure just as a way to organize data), the behavior of that data structure does not necessarily represent an ADT.

Comment: Of course that car doesn't represent and ADT, but you can abstract that car with a particular behaviours and then it become in an ADT. Right?

Comment: I think we're veering too much into metaphysics. I mean, an ADT exists because it's useful, not because of some intrinsic property. A car is not "abstract" enough to be considered an ADT. IMHO simply because it is a very concrete thing. A list of messages can be represented in the abstract as a queue (an ADT). That is, an ADT is meant as an abstraction. It doesn't derive from a data structure, but it can be implemented with a data structure. I have the impression you're thinking about this backwards, or maybe it's just me and I can't express clearly what I mean.

Comment: You are explaining perfectly, the real problem for my understand is, why someone can say that a heap is not and adt, for example, because you can implemente this with an array, and with a pointer, maybe not in the same time complexity, but I think that is an ADT too, also, for example can you say that dinamic array are and ADT, or is an dinamic array a data structure of a list?, who define officialy list? thus, you can say too that you have the array like adt and its implementation like a DT, right? thanks for your answers

Comment: I'll try to put it in other terms (*very* simplified and *not rigorous at all*): an ADT is "I can do these operations on an entity", a data structure is "to implement this entity I need to do this". A heap is an implementation detail. You can insert things and get things from it, but this is also the definition of a Map (which is an ADT). A heap is a particular way of implementing a map. Just like you can implement queues, lists and stacks (even maps, if you like wasting time :P) with a dynamic array. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca *a heap is a particular way of implementing a map.* Not really. I mean, you *could* implement a map in a heap, but it would be terribly inefficient: like a list. Heap is an implementation of the priority queue ADT. A map is something quiet different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

Comment: @JimMischel you're right, I was thinking of hash tables, not heaps. I got confused.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the last comment is very clear for understand thanks

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I response in the other question, if you can check it too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57594669/11901332